# 'c' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

In my grade average code I have the letter grades a, b, c, d, and f, but when I try to run it, it was that my letter was not declared in this scope. I do not know what this means.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

string average(int g);

int main()
{
    int grade;

    cout << "Enter your grade:" << endl;
    cin >> grade;

    cout << "Your grade is a" << average(grade) << "!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

string average(int g)
{
    if (g >= 90 && g <= 100)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if(g >= 80 && g <90)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else if (g > 70 && g < 80)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else if (g == 70)
    {
        return d;
    }
    else if (g < 70)
    {
        return f;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try `return "a"` instead of `return a`. In the first case it is returning grade string/text "a". In the second case(in your original code) it is trying to look for variable `a` which is not in scope. And that is the complaint it is throwing at you.

Comment: This doesn’t address the problem, but you don’t need all those `<` checks in the `if ... else if` ladder. If `g` is 95 the first branch will be taken, and the `g < 90` in the second branch has no effect. Same for the second test in  all the rest of those expressions. So: `if (g >= 90) ... else if (g >= 80) ... else if (g >= 70) ... else ...`

Answer (score -1):

You have nowhere declared grades - a, b, c, d, e, f in your program.
How would compiler know that a represents grade-a, b represents grade-b and so on.

You can probably use enum to declare grades, like this -

```
enum grades {a='a', b='b', c='c', d='d', e='e', f='f'};
```

There are other ways to do this.
Whatever you use to achieve your goal, you need to modify your program based on your decision.